# Only latest used SATA port recognized in bios

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios, sata

I'm having a problem with my bios reading my harddrives. I have two harddrives with two separate Operating Systems on it. I'm trying to be able to choose which harddrive to load through the bios. When I enter the bios, I only see the last used harddrive.

For example.

If I disconnect SATA 1 and use SATA2, I can load SATA 2. If I reconnect SATA1 I can still only use SATA 2. 
Same goes the other way. If I disconnect SATA 2 then I can only use SATA 1.

Why is this happening and how do I make it so they are both read in the bios?

My setup is:

Intel i7 
MSI z77A-G43 MSI Motherboard
One OS is linux on an SSD drive and the other is Windows on a HHD drive.

Let me know if any other specs are required to help troubleshoot.

Comment: That's very strange! Have you updated you bios? Have you always had this behaviour? What is your motherboard / system?

Comment: I believe this behavior has always been with my motherboard. I have posted some of the specs above if that helps. I'm going to try updating it right now in the hopes that fixes it.

Comment: This might actually be a feature of your mainboard to improve boot up times. Moving my comment to an answer, since it's rather long and I think that's the "issue" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might actually be a feature of your mainboard to improve boot up times. My new mainboard (Asus Z87-Pro) has this as a specific feature to be enabled:

You can limit UEFI/BIOS to only read/initialize bootable drives connected to known SATA ports.

So if I connect another drive, I'll have to boot and shutdown once for it to appear in the boot menu, since at first it's not detected (since not known to be bootable).

Comment: Hmm...that might make sense. I was playing around with the bios and the bios is detected SATA 2 and SATA 3 (SATA 3 connects with my dvd). I am surprised though it doesn't even show up in the Override section of my bios.

Comment: What was the setting called under your bios?

Comment: So I found out it is a setting in the bios. I haven't found the setting to allow me to read both drives at the same time (it is still limited) but if I change the harddrive boot priority I can at least decide which harddrive to boot.

Comment: Most systems will allow you to override the default order without changing the actual boot priorities. You should never have to connect/disconnect drives for this to work. If you want some interactive menu to select the bootable drive, use a tool such as *BCDEdit* to modify Windows' boot menu and add the alternative system.